# react-native-signature-capture ref dilemma

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture for getting signature from users in my app.

I am using two signature-capture in the same screen , and need to call resetImage image from a custom button ( done through refs ) .
But what happens is that when i call any function from the refs , all are being called to last rendered element only.

ie , call resetImage always clear sign in the second sign only, even if the call from first or second signature capture.

I am stuck on this for two day , any idea to solve this ?

```
<SignatureCapture key={`signFirst`}
  ref={r=>{
      this.signFirstRef = r
    }} 
  />
/*----custom button used */
<SignatureClearButton
  onPress={()=>{
    this.signFirstRef.resetImage()/* This call will clear signSecond image only */
  }}
  />

<SignatureCapture key={`signSecond`}
  ref={r=>{
      this.signSecondRef = r
    }} 
  />
/*----custom button used */
<SignatureClearButton
  onPress={()=>{
    this.signSecondRef.resetImage()
  }}
  />
```

platform : IOS

haven't checked on android yet